# font attr in placeholder is none. how to get the real value of the font in placeholder

Tags: python-pptx

Currently, I have also encountered an issue where when I use placeholder, its font attribute is all set to none. And changing it does not affect the font of the slide placeholder. How should I obtain the font of the text displayed by the placeholder

i try to get the runs.font.name in layoutplaceholder.but it replys none. also,i try to get it in slideplaceholder, it replys none.i want to get the real font.name of text in placeholder, eg Arial

Comment: I would create an empty run (or a nearly empty run) - and then query it.